# Python while, continue loops

Tags: python, while-loop

My input file is one sentence per line. Let's say it looks like:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

Desired output is:

```
::NewPage::
A
B
::NewPage::
C
D
::NewPage::
E
F
```

I know that I should be using a while loop but not sure how to?

Comment: So where exactly do you have problems? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a `while` loop here - look at [the `grouper` recipe](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) in [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html).

```
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

Note that you will need [a slightly different version](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) if you are using 2.x.

E.g:

```
items = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
for page in grouper(2, items):
    print("::NewPage::")
    for item in page:
        if item is not None:
            print(item)
```

Which produces:

```
::NewPage::
A
B
::NewPage::
C
D
::NewPage::
E
```

If you need `None` values, you can use a sentinel object.

Comment: Don't forget to note the Python 2 recipes in case @Sabba is using that version.  http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes

Comment: @zigg I was just adding that note in.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if this might bother the gods of the PEP-8.

But a language agnostic alternative (understandable by a more generic audience) might be:

```
items = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
out = []

for i,item in enumerate(items):
    if i%2 == 0:
        out.append("::New Page::")
    out.append(item)
```

Edit: this is what happens when you dont check if there's a new answer before finishing writing yours. My answer is basicallly the same as cdarke's.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?  Tested on Python 3.3:

```
i = 0
page_size = 2
lines = []

for line in open("try.txt"):
    lines.append(line)
    i += 1
    if i % page_size == 0:
        print("::NewPage::")
        print("".join(lines),end="")
        i = 0
        lines = []
```